# using _.reject turns my object into an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have some data that I want to iterate through and reject those with a `disabled: true` property.

however when I try `_.reject` my object gets turned into an array.

```
var data = {
  stuff: {
     item1: {
        name: "one",
        disabled: true
     },
     item2: {
        name: "two"
     }

  }
};


data.stuff = _.reject(data.stuff, function(val){
    return val.disabled;
});
```

`data.stuff` is now an array, rather than an Object. I've lost all my keys.

Comment: `_.reject` can only return an array.

Comment: Semantically, your `stuff` actually even *should* be an array. Really. `item1`, `item2` either is useful data (then turn it into an `id` property, respectively) or it isn't (then drop it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using native javascript instead of underscore:

```
//remove disabled items
for ( var item in data.stuff ) {
    if ( data.stuff[item].disabled ) {
        delete data.stuff[item];
    }
}
```

Comment: i like this Vanilla JS solution, but it would have been best if it worked inline like you were originally trying. for the only solution herein that works, try @Gruff Bunny's answer +1

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`_.omit()`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) instead.

Comment: doesn't work - omit returns the same data, even when sent `data.stuff`

Answer (score 4):

What @archie said but in code:

```
data.stuff = _.reduce(data.stuff, function(memo, value, key){
    if( !value.disabled) memo[key] = value;
    return memo;
}, {});
```

Comment: this is the only solution in this question that will work inline (returning data) and actually returns the correct answer ::: `{ item2:{ name:"two" } }`

Comment: In fact, `omit()` is better, because it's a tool intended precisely for the job at hand.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass `data.stuff` (which is an Object) to `_.reject`, it picks only the values of the object and passes that to `_.reject`. So, `key` information is lost and reconstructing the object is not possible.

Instead, you can do it like this

```
data.stuff = _.object(_.filter(_.pairs(data.stuff), function(list) {
    return list[1].disabled;
}));

console.log(data);
```

**Output**

```
{ stuff: { item1: { name: 'one', disabled: true } } }
```

**How it works**

1. [`_.pairs`](http://underscorejs.org/#pairs) converts the `{key:value}` pairs into `[key, value]` array.
2. [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) filters the items whose `disabled` is a falsy value.
3. [`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object) converts the filtered `[key, value]` array into `{key:value}` pairs.

Comment: While this works, there's a much simpler solution using `omit()`. See below.

Comment: this solution is tailored to underscore but `_.pairs` is not a fn in lodash

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs#omit):

```
_.omit(data.stuff, function(val) { return val.disabled; });
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehbmsb5k/

Comment: does not work - omit returns the same data, even passed sent `data.stuff`

Comment: @gdibble It does indeed work. I updated answer with a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at doing this with _reduce, where the memo is a new hash, in which you merge the items( key, value pair) you need.

Answer (score -1):

The original `data.stuff` is not changed when you use `reject`. But since you are assigning to  the `stuff` key, the original data is lost.

`_.reject` is supposed to work on and return arrays. You could try this in order to accomplish what you want:

```
_.each(Object.keys(data.stuff), function(val) {
    if (data.stuff[val].disabled)
        delete data.stuff[val];
});
```

Comment: ): returned `["item1", "item2"]`